# installing Angstrom on Beaglebone black

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux

I am a newbie in Beaglebone Black, I install Ubuntu on my Beaglebone Black which works fine, Now I am trying to install Angstrom on Beaglebone Black, for this I first of all download image of Angstrom "Angstrom-Cloud9-IDE-GNOME-eglibc-ipk-v2012.12-beaglebone-2013.08.21.img" , then extract it using "7Zip" , after that I use "Win32 Disk Imager" to copy it into a 16 GB SD card.Now insert my SD card in Beaglebone Black. Then I press boot button and after that I provide power supply using 5v and 1 Amp  adapter. After making sure that all four LED's are glowing , I release boot button.
        Now the problem is the installation should be completed in around 45 minute and all four LED's should become stable , but in my case LED's keeps blinking. I check it more than four times for around more than one and a half hour and after that I take out the power supply and check Beaglebone Board on my desktop monitor, surprisingly Ubuntu is Still there.So, please tell where is the problem.

Comment: I followed step on this link http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Updating_The_Software. But I have a Ubuntu machine. Therefore I didn't have to use DiskImager and 7-zip. But I did have to flash a the SD card about 3 times before I got it working. In my case it took about 20-30 minutes to load the kernel to on board flash. Good Luck

Comment: image you are booting might be SD card image, if this is the case then it will boot from SD card only it will not be flashed to EMMC of BeagleBone Balck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also installed Angstrom on BeagleBoard Black.
You should follow derek molloy tutorial. Here is the link to [tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/write-a-new-image-to-the-beaglebone-black/)

It should boot up in 10 seconds. It will not take 45 minute to boot up if properly installed.

Comment: I follow that tutorial actually but see point no 10, its mention there it will take some time, but any ways i tried it as you say, but still ubutu is there

Comment: Ok, In that case you should install `debian` if Angstrom doesn't boot up after 45 minutes. Debian is better than angstrom.

Comment: please share tutorial link if have.

Comment: Follow these links
http://thethingsystem.com/dev/Bootstrapping-the-BeagleBone-Black-with-Debian.html
http://beagleboard.org/latest-images
http://beagleboard.org/project/debian

Comment: Thanks sir, its working, I was really stuck with ubuntu, thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1):

Use this file "BBB-eMMC-flasher-2013.09.04" under BeagleBone Black (eMMC flasher) for flashing to eMMC